# HTML Form Submit is not working in Android 4.0. The same code is working fine in the lower versions of Android

Tags: android

Form Submit is not working in Android 4.0. The same code is working fine in the lower versions of Android and higher version like jelly bean.  document.myForm.submit()  called it goes to next page and values are added such page.html?value= "". but page not found is coming it takes this as complete URL instead of form sumbit

Answer (score 0):

Android 4.0 is not accepting the page submit itself even "?" is considered as part of your HTML file. I overide the WebViewClient

```
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    public String values = "";
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if (url.contains("?")) {
            try {
                values = URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            url = url.replace("?", "%45");
            String args[] = url.split("%45");
            view.loadUrl(args[0]);
        }else{
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if(values.length()>0){
            if(url.contains("smartmodesresult.html")){
                mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:getUrlVars(\""+values+"\");");
            }
        }
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }

}
```